# MySQL INSERT Query

Tags: mysql, insert

I need a query to perform the following:
find the countryID where country = 'UK' from table Countries

then use the found value in

```
INSERT into towns (id, country_fk, name)
values (1, <value_found>, 'London').
```

is this possible?

*UPDATE* I need to store the value once so that I can use it in multiple INSERTS (about 100)

Comment: Have you considered using an auto-incremented field for the id of the town?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. One option is to use the [INSERT ... SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html), as follows:

```
INSERT INTO towns (id, country_fk, name)
SELECT 1, countryID, 'London' FROM countries WHERE country = 'UK';
```

Comment: @vittore: We call it the "fastest gun in the west" problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: @mouthpiec: Hey, what a surprise to meet a compatriot! :)

Comment: @stereofrog: ...but faster from the other "exactly the same" answer(s) :)

Comment: indeed, INSERT ... SELECT is more nice here. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery there:

```
INSERT into towns (id, country_fk, name)
values (1, (SELECT countryID from countries where country = 'UK'), 'London')
```

Comment: thanks zerkms, but I need to store the value once so that I can use it in multiple INSERTS (about 100)

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where country = 'UK'), 'London')'`

Comment: @Mark: the answer was missing the 'from' clause - are you getting any errors now?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into towns(id, countrt_fk, name)
select 1 , countrt_fk , 'London' from Countries where country = 'UK'
```